# Using Decreasing Variable as NSTimeInterval in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I am trying to decrease a Double variable by 0.05 every second to speed up the function spawnEnemy() but I cannot find a way that works well. So, I am trying to pretty much "spawn" more enemies(UIButtons) in a shorter amount of time. Any help would be great and very appreciated. Thank you! My code below compiles fine but does not speed up the NSTimer controlling the function spawnEnemy()

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    var points: Int = 0

    func randomPoint() -> CGPoint {
        let randomPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random()%320),y:CGFloat(568-arc4random()%390))
        return randomPoint
    }

    func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    func spawnEnemy() {
        let enemy: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 160, y: 160, width: 100, height: 100))
        enemy.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        enemy.center = randomPoint()
        enemy.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonPushed:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(enemy)
    }

    func buttonPushed(sender : UIButton) {
        if sender.frame.height < 50 || sender.frame.width < 50 {
            sender.frame = CGRectMake(sender.frame.origin.x, sender.frame.origin.y, 50, 50)
            sender.backgroundColor = randomColor()
            sender.center = randomPoint()
            return
        }
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        points = points + 1
        scoreLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        scoreLabel.text = "\(points)"
        scoreLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    func decreaseDouble() -> Double {
        var num: Double = 2.0
        num = num - 0.05
        return num
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(decreaseDouble(), target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("decreaseDouble"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

Below is my new code. Any finals things or should this work? I also added a while statement so you can only receive points while the enemy is not black,otherwise you could just keep clicking on wherever enemies have been spawned(but were clicked) and keep getting points. However, now when i run the application two enemies are already spawned but i can still click on them(only being allowed to get two points)

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    var points: Int = 0

    func randomPoint() -> CGPoint {
        let randomPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random()%320),y:CGFloat(568-arc4random()%390))
        return randomPoint
    }

    func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    func spawnEnemy() {
        let enemy: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 160, y: 160, width: 100, height: 100))
        enemy.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        enemy.center = randomPoint()
        enemy.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonPushed:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(enemy)
    }

    func buttonPushed(sender : UIButton) {
        if sender.frame.height < 50 || sender.frame.width < 50 {
            sender.frame = CGRectMake(sender.frame.origin.x, sender.frame.origin.y, 50, 50)
            sender.backgroundColor = randomColor()
            sender.center = randomPoint()
            return
        }
        while sender.backgroundColor != UIColor.blackColor() {
            points = points + 1
            scoreLabel.textAlignment = .Center
            scoreLabel.text = "\(points)"
            scoreLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
        delayTime -= 0.05
    }

    var delayTime: Double = 2.0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delayTime = 2.0

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(delayTime, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea.  I would use the repeating timer as a 'tick' and then keep two properties - One is the tick count and the other is the tick count before a new enemy is spawned.  By decreasing the latter you can speed up the rate of spawning.

Something like this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    var points: Int = 0

    var tickCount=0    

    var spawnRate=100   // Spawn every 10 seconds to start with

    var spawnTimer:NSTimer!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tickCount=self.spawnRate

        self.spawnTimer=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("tick"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func tick() {
       if (--tickCount == 0) {
          self.spawnEnemy()
          self.spawnRate=spawnRate - 2  // Change this to determine how quickly the spawn rate increases
          self.tickCount=self.spawnRate
       }
    }
```

You can modify the tick rate and tick decrement amounts as required to give you the range you are after

Comment: That would work too, but I think you'd need finer than .1 seconds for the tick. I'd suggest using .05, or even .02

Comment: I am trying o have the spawnRate go 20-0, then 0-20 with increments of one by adding else if (self.spawnRate == 0) {
            self.spawnEnemy()
            self.spawnRate=spawnRate + 1
            self.tickCount=self.spawnRate
        } in the tick method but what happens is that once it hits 0, it just keeps spawning in enemies. How would i make it so that once it loop sort of thing?

Answer (score 2):

Repeating `NSTimers` always fire on the same interval once you start them.

If you want to use a decreasing interval then instead of a repeating timer I suggest use use a **single** "one-shot" timer (not 2 timers). Create the timer with `repeats:false`. Then in your timer method (`spawnEnemy`, in your case) decrement your time interval and use it to create a new timer (also with `repeats:false`) using the new, shorter interval and calling the same method.

Your decreaseDouble function isn't going to work as written. It will always return the same value of 2.0 - 0.05, since you set num to 2.0 each time the function called. Instead get rid of the decreaseDouble function. Create an instance variable `delayValue` and assign it a value (2.0, for example) in your viewDidLoad. Then just subtract 0.05 from it each time spawnEnemy is called, spawn a new enemy, and create a new timer if `delayValue` hasn't gotten too small. (When `delayValue` gets really small you're going to be spawning 10 enemies a second. Eventually `delayValue` will go to zero, and a timer interval should not be <= 0.0.

Comment: So, I would essentially have to create a good amount of NSTimers if I wanted to gradually speed the method up?

Comment: You only create one timer at a time. Each time your timer fires, it gets invalidated since it's a "one-shot". I edited my answer to provide more info. Go re-read it.

Comment: I have donned worked with similar stuff before but then what happens to the NSTimeInterval especially if I will need many NSTimers?? Because the NSTimerInterval is essentially just a number that represents how many seconds the NSTimer will wait in between performing functions unless the NSTimer is set to repeats:false like you said. Thank you.

Comment: Wait. I understand the concept but how do I put that new number into the new NSTimer? Would I need to create a variable like I was trying to use?

Comment: Except have it inside the method that is being called on? i.e. spawnEnemy()

Comment: I will attempt it and then edit my post showing how I did and if it worked.

Comment: This isn't that complicated. Create an instance variable delayTime. Set it to 2.0 in viewDidLoad. In viewDidLoad also create a timer with an interval of delayTime (and `repeats:false`) and make the timer call `spawnEnemy`. In spawnEnemy, create a new enemy, then decrement delayTime if it's not too small. (You should probably stop subtracting 0.05. from it after it gets to 0.5 or so - whatever you decide is the shortest delay between creating enemies.) Then create a new (non-repeating) timer with the new interval that also calls spawnEnemy.

Comment: Why would the second also be non-repeating?

Comment: Because each timer only times the next interval. Each time the timer fires, you want to have the amount of time until the next timer be the new, slightly shorter interval. Remember, repeating timers ALWAYS fire at the same interval. Instead of a repeating timer your creating a series of 1-shot timers, each with a slightly shorter interval than the last.

Comment: The code above builds but once the simulator loads two enemies are already spawned and they do not continue because both NSTimers are set to false. I do understand how to create a series of single-shot timers using only two NSTimers. Thank you for your help, though.

Comment: This is not hard. You only need ONE single-shot timer at any one time. When it fires, in your spawnEnemy method, create a new timer for the next interval.

Comment: But you literally just said, "create a new timer"

Comment: Right. One timer at a time. When each timer fires, create the next one.

Comment: Oh, ok, but how could I "create the next one" if I am only supposed to be using one? My current code is above if you want to check that out for reference.

Comment: ARGHHH!  Only one timer at a time. When the first timer fires, it's invalidated. Your code creates 2 timers when it starts: `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(delayTime, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`. Don't do that. Only create one timer, wait for it to fire, and then create another single timer.

Comment: "and then create another singular timer" I am sorry, but I am just a beginner and clearly I am not seeing what is so obvious. How do I create ANOTHER timer with only ONE timer...